# Ranking in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` text NOT NULL,
  `song` text NOT NULL,
  `vote` int(11) NOT NULL
```

I have created a voting system and I would like to print the songs with more votes ... how do I do it? Thank you

Comment: Basically what are you asking? is it the SQL query? or a PHP script? what you have tried so far?

Comment: What do you  mean `more` more then what?

Comment: That's why I do not know where to leave, I would need a script in php, where to check which songs have more votes and print the 10 most voted songs

Comment: i mean you asking about result as Maximum peoples Voted Songs Right?
so it means you need to specific Songs Total Vote Counting.

Comment: Practically I would like to extract all the votes in the table and then add up

Comment: But Any one can tell me why my answer was down voted :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to try for counting total votes for the song

```
SELECT SUM(vote)as VOTECOUNT, song FROM votes GROUP BY song ORDER BY SUM(vote) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: And how do I mold this in php? Do I need a loop to print the top ten?

Comment: @Cristoforo i edit my code now you can see its return top 10 **VOTECOUNT** and in your php if you can get top 10 records.
Why you are down the my answer.

Comment: Yes, defiantly you need to used foreach loop to print this 10 records

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your table contains each single vote.
I also assume that song is unique ID of a song.
If that is so you need to sum the values of vote and divide it to the total votes.

```
SELECT song, SUM(vote)/COUNT(*) AS rateing FROM your_table_name GROUP BY song ORDER BY rateing DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try below query.you can get higest voted songs.
put your table name in 'table_name'.

SELECT song,SUM(vote)as VOTECOUNT FROM table_name GROUP BY song order by VOTECOUNT desc