# Fetching Data from database and Displaying it

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a simple Review form that allows the user to write a review and rate the service.

First Issue : I don't know how the star rating works(might delete it), I can't get it into the database. WHat is the best way to store and display the stars submitted?

Second Issue : How could i display the Name and Comment to fit this html code ? And keep it there for everyone to see, and then i would like to have latest reviews at the top.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x60/666/ffffff&text=No+Image" class="img-rounded">
    <div class="review-block-name"><a href="#">(PrintNameFromDatabase)</a></div>
    <div class="review-block-date">January 29, 2016<br/>1 day ago</div>
  </div>
<div class="review-block-title">PrintCommentFromDatabase</div>
</div>
```

PHP Form insert:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);
include ('connect.php');
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $comments = $_POST['comment'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Comment) VALUES (?, ?)"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $comments);   
    $stmt->execute();  
    header ('Location: index.php');

?>

<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if( ! is_numeric($id) )
      die('invalid article id');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Persons` WHERE `id` =$id LIMIT 0 , 30";
    $comments = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    $name = $row['Name'];
      $comment = $row['Comments'];

    }
?>
```

I am using this code to get the data from the database.

**UPDATE: I am getting redirected to 'somebadwebsite' when i try to run the PHP display script.**

**As comments stated i was using deprecated version of MySql I shouldve have used PDO or mysqli**

Comment: i just give you the link for how to set i mean voting and see answer here [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964269/ranking-in-php-and-mysql/44964508#44964508) For the First Issue.
and please explain me more about where is your code to display the Name and Comment to fit html code??

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya Update my answer, My question is: how Can i display it there..., Do i need to use sessions for every user?

Comment: Noted Sir! @Wojetek T Please visite here [DOMDocument()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php)

Comment: **The `mysql` PHP extension is dead** -- Stop using the [`mysql` PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). It is old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead. And **don't mix them!**